# Display the text only if attribute value = "yes" in magneto site

Tags: magento

we have custom dropdown attribute with values : **"YES" or "NO"** in  backend.

I want to display the text in view page only if value = "yes"

attribute code : **name_order** . below is code.

```
<?php echo "display text"; ?>
```

Comment: Is it a product oder customer attribute? Which view are talking about exactly?

Comment: @codedge `name_order` is custom attribute code & in ` Productview page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Set "Used in Product View page" to Yes

Then in view.phtml :

```
if($_product->getAttributeText('name_order')=='yes')
{
    echo "display text";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the template `app/design/frontend/default/<YOUR THEME>/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and you implemented the attribute correctly you can access it via

```
$_product->getNameOrder()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's a product attribute?

If so, you can get value of your attribute per product by using the `getAttributeText()` method.

```
<?php
    if($_product->getAttributeText("name_order") == "Yes") {
        echo "Set to Yes";
    } else {
        echo "Set to No";
    }
?>
```